# Pets is graduating!

Tags: discussion

We have recently received the good news that Pets will be graduating from Beta next month!

Based on the longevity of the site, and number of questions and answers, Stack Exchange has determined that Pets is ready to leave Beta.

The graduation date is set for 16 Dec 2021.

There may not be many changes you notice immediately, but there will be a few changes going forward.

- Beta label will be removed.
- Expect a moderator election most likely some point in 2022. Up until now, the moderators have been pro-tem moderators. With graduated sites, an election will be held in which the current moderators as well as any community members who wish to be nominated may run.
- In the past, site customisation was a benefit of graduation. As many sites have recently graduated, this is not something that will change soon, but in the future we may get a custom colour scheme or logo - just don’t expect these things immediately.
- Features such as migration paths and community ads become available.

This wouldn’t be possible without everyone who contributed over the past 8 years. Thank you all!

Comment: *Whoot* That's good news ;)

Comment: Woohoo! Congrats to the whole community and all their efforts!