# Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2022

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Pets Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://pets.stackexchange.com/election/4) on **August 8, 2022**, as your “graduation” election as a result of [having lost your beta label a while back](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2382/3847).

The timeline:

- On August 1, 2022, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on August 8, 2022, users can [nominate themselves](https://pets.stackexchange.com/election/4). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On August 15, 2022, if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 23, 2022 (or August 30, 2022, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

I started off as a small site moderator - and the lack of things to do compared to my bigger sites can sometimes be an issue. What would you feel are the essential things you need to do as a moderator here?

Comment: Pets is a small site and there is very little to do for mods. The main work is dealing with "not an answer" flags and the occasional spam. About once or twice a year there's a problematic user to be dealt with. Personally I think Pets is a very good place for people to experience what it's like to be a mod for the first time without having too many responsibilities or being overwhelmed with tasks.

Comment: Am I sensing a hat being already juggled in one hand, ready to be thrown into the ring?

Comment: Well - I was toying with it the last round, but figured I would need to quit if I successfully got hired as a community manager. That's something at best in the further future now so it's something in consideration if I feel I am a good fit for what the community needs

Comment: In short, maybe 