# We're celebrating the 10th anniversary of Pets.SE!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, event

it's been 10 years since this site took its first baby steps. There have been ups and downs, warm welcomes and goodbyes. Time to celebrate, to remember and to share some fun facts!

**We invite everyone to share their best memories or anecdotes about this site.** It doesn't matter if you joined us 10 years ago or yesterday. How did you join this community? Do you remember any fun interactions or chat messages? Any heartwarming moments? Maybe dig up some questions or answers that had an impact on you.

Feel free to share photos of your pets here (please limit yourself to 3 photos). It's always great to see the diversity of animal species and individuals we as the Pets community have catered to over the years.

To start, I'd like to remind you of our [1st Year Anniversary Party](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1885).

Answer (score 4):

When I became a member of Pets.SE, I had a dog that was abused and abandoned by his first owners and had some very problematic behavior, so I was forced to learn a lot about dog's body language and how they think. Answering questions of people with similar problems made me feel useful and I stuck around ever since.

Even though I thought I already knew a lot about dogs, I still learned a lot about them and even had to change my own beliefs. For example I thought that intact males were more aggressive because of their hormones and neutering would make them easier to train, but it turns out that [neutering can make dogs more aggressive and harder to train](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31153/12501) than before.

I also believed in the old "dominance theory" of dogs and I'm very grateful to the members who pointed out in the comments to some of my answers that it was
[complete rubbish](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/2987/12501).

My funniest moment was when I learned that [gold fish can be taught tricks and even formation swimming.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21199/12501)

My biggest scare was when I thought [someone had taken in a rabid dog](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/29900/12501), but to my grat relief it turned out the dog was blind and probably confused.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations to everyone on Pets SE and Happy Anniversary. I want to thank Elmy, Journeyman Geek, and Harry V. I was so excited [when Pets lost the Beta label](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382/pets-is-graduating) a couple of years ago.

As a pet owner and as someone who likes to volunteer with animal rescue organizations the knowledge this community has shared over the past decade has been a valuable resource. I've enjoyed [contributing a little bit](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/34487/what-is-average-weight-of-newzealand-albino-rabbit/37102#37102) to that collective knowledge during Community-a-thons.

I'm sharing a photo of my pet rabbit Cleo for the selfish reason that I hope some of you will share photos of your pets on this post. Thank you for all that this community does.

[image: brown bunny rabbit with lop ears sitting next to a blue tunnel tube]

Answer (score 1):

Happy Anniversary pets.SE!

10 years are quite old for dogs, rabbits or horses, for turtles or parrots 10 years are around half-time and for humans it is still childhood. So we have a proper mix of experience, maternity and energy level here :)

When I started here some years ago, I read a lot to get better skills in english language. So I see now how complicated my sentences were this time ago ^^ i.e. I did not know the difference between turtles and tortoise (in German they both are named "Schildkröte").

For me important is, to open up the SE community as non native speaker. Lots of users with native English language skills seem not aware, that this site is for users world wide and so also proposes solutions and knowledge from around the world :)

Since more than 15 years now I have a turtle called "Fritzi". Since around 8 years I have rabbits, actual two female and one male, called "Tom", "Blackberry" and "Primrose".

[image: Turtle at sunset]
This summer Fritzi had a short experience in the garden. Usually he lives in a nearly 2000l tank.

[image: two rabbits looking for a cat]
Blackberry and Primrose focus the neighbours cat. They are very aware to protect each other and warn everyone around by stomping the back leg. (The lazy cat does not come into our garden. The rabbit-safe fences need to much afford to jump over for the cat's taste)